# What are good cases for using __if_exists?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When do I use [`__if_exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7wy9xh3(v=vs.80).aspx) without writing tons of crappy code?

Looks like this keyword is like C preprocessor directive, but is processed after preprocessor. And IntelliSense doesn't parse it and highlight code as dead or alive. These together make analysis of code written with `__if_exists` really non-trivial.

So far I found only one relatively safe case. We have a container class that takes an address of stored object. When a class stored has an overloaded `operator&` that overloaded operator is called and this causes problems.

So I added the following check:

```
__if_exists( T::operator& ) {
   static_assert( false );
}
```

and now the code at least won't compile if there's an `operator&` member function is the type stored.

IMO this use case is quite clear and easy to read.

What other cases are there of using `__if_exists` without getting tons of unreadable code?

Comment: The same sort of things as [SFINAE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sfinae) checks in templates? I hadn't heard if __if_exists, neat.

Comment: @Rup: Can SFINAE be used to detect a *particular* member function?

Comment: I'd be careful about using __if_exists if you plan to port to other platforms; I'm pretty sure it's Microsoft specific.

Comment: @Nawaz don't know, I've only seen SFINAE used to detect child types of template parameters. But they're both compile time checks on template parameters so I expect they'd have the same sorts of applications.

Comment: @Nawaz, apparently you can: http://www.ideone.com/gpUU5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use it to distinguish unions and classes, since classes do have constructors and unions don't.

You'd want this in e.g. `boost::type_traits::is_class<T>` and `boost::type_traits::is_union<T>`

Answer (score 3):

Though I'm not sure this is always possible or useful, `__if_exists` can be
used as `static if` in D language in a sense.
For example, the following code prints `b`.

```
template< bool > struct static_if_t;
template<> struct static_if_t< true > {};
#define STATIC_IF( c )     __if_exists    ( static_if_t< (c) > )
#define STATIC_UNLESS( c ) __if_not_exists( static_if_t< (c) > )

struct X {
  static bool const v = false;
};

STATIC_IF( X::v ) {
  void f() { puts("a"); }
}
STATIC_UNLESS( X::v ) {
  void f() { puts("b"); }
}

int main() {
  f(); // prints "b"
}
```